# Overriding git-commit-id-plugin defaults in Spring Boot

Tags: git, maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

How would one override the defaults from *spring-boot-starter-parent*
for the ***git-commit-id-plugin***, putting the following into ***build/plugins*** doesn't seem to do the trick:

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>

            <configuration>
                <abbrevLength>10</abbrevLength>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Still seeing default short versions in the generated *git.properties*:

```
git.commit.id.describe-short=05780bf
git.commit.id.describe=05780bf
```

Update:

As per **@kan's** suggestion below, I tried the following:

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>

                <configuration>

                    <abbrevLength>10</abbrevLength>
                    <gitDescribe>
                    <abbrev>10</abbrev>
                    </gitDescribe>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

which produced the following in *git.properties*:

```
git.commit.id.abbrev=8b8a2f7
git.commit.id.describe-short=8b8a2f727c
git.commit.id.describe=8b8a2f727c
```

However, the */info* endpoint of Spring Boot app still displays the shortened version, apparently from **git.commit.id.abbrev**:

```
{

    "application": 

{

    "name": "broker-feed"

},
"build": 
{

    "version": "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

},
"git": 
{

    "branch": "master",
    "commit": 

        {
            "id": "8b8a2f7",
            "time": "2015-08-28T13:00:49-0400"
        }
    }

}
```

Could Spring Boot plugin be redirected to pick another version or am I missing something else along the way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Tryto  specify it in the gitDesribe section:

```
<configuration>
  <gitDescribe>
    <abbrev>10</abbrev>
  </gitDescribe>
</configuration>
```

The `abbrevLength` is for `git.commit.id.abbrev`, and `gitDescribe/abbrev` is for `git.commit.id.describe`.

Comment: kan: Please check an updated description incorporating results of your suggestion.

Comment: @SimeonLeyzerzon Weird. Which version of the plugin do you use?

Comment: This is happening on version 2.1.15 of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can configure the content of the /info endpoint, and add whatever you want from your git.properties.

For example, this is what we use in our application.properties

```
# actuator's info endpoint
info.build.user=${git.build.user.name}
info.build.host=${git.build.host}
info.build.latest=${git.commit.message.full}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue should be fixed with Spring Boot 1.5.3, (see the pull request [Use git.commit.id.abbrev if present](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/8781)).

Simply configure the length of the property `git.commit.id.abbrev` via the plugin's `abbrevLength` configuration and Spring Boot will now pick it up.